# How to make Vaadin 10 components change one by one from click event?

Tags: java, concurrency, vaadin

For some reason components are always changed from button click simultaneously. 
 I need to change them one by one. Here is the example:

```
countButton.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> {
    int input = Integer.parseInt(inputTextField.getValue());

    long factorialResult = countFactorial(input);
    resultFactorialLabel.setText("Factorial: " + factorialResult);

    //just for example, could be processing that takes really long
    try {
        sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
    }

    int fibonacciResult = countFibonacci(input);
    resultFibonacciLabel.setText("Fibonacci: " + fibonacciResult);
});
```

When I run it - 10 seconds passes, then resultFactorialLabel and resultFibonacciLabel change simultaneously, when I want resultFactorialLabel to be changed and after that, in 10 seconds, resultFibonacciLabel to be changed. How can I do it? 
And how is it made so, that labels change simultaneously?

Vaadin version: 10.0.1

Comment: You need push and a background thread for that.  Your method there get called synchronous on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the usual lifecycle:

- An event occurs on the client side (browser), e.g. a click on a button.
- This makes a HTTP call to the server (your Vaadin application).
- Vaadin processes the call, firing the event on the server, i.e. executing all registered listeners for the event, e.g. your click listener.
- In the listener, you do some changes on the (server-side) components, e.g. updating a label.
- After that, a response is sent to the client containing information about all the changed components.
- Then, on the client side, the HTML is updated to reflect the changed components.

So if you do a `sleep` within your listener, it will just delay the response to the client.

If you need to do an expensive operation triggered by the button click, you should do it in a background thread and update the UI once the operation is complete. See [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access.html) for how to update UI from a background thread.